# In a virtual environment of PyCharm,i can't import numpy.from ctypes import WinDLL ImportError: No module named ctypes

Tags: numpy, import, pycharm, python-venv

```
import os
import hashlib
from collections import defaultdict
import numpy
file_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
res_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(file_dir, '..', '..'))
print "res dir:", res_dir

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

just code as before，i got error

```
File D:\client\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py, line 12, in <module>
    from ctypes import WinDLL
ImportError: No module named ctypes
```

and pycharm can not install ctypes,i dont know how to set it.